# Heroku CLI Unresponsive

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have been using the Heroku CLI for some time now without incident. Shortly after deploying a batch of new code today, it became totally unresponsive. When entering a command (e.g. heroku status) it just hangs forever. Doesn't matter what command I enter, it hangs. I've restarted my terminal and also tried killing the Heroku CLI process a few times, but the problem persists.

How can I debug the problem? Is it my installation or is it a Heroku problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was this issue https://status.heroku.com/incidents/769

it doesn't lock up forever, but 120 seconds. It will fix itself.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exact problem today after running heroku run rails c, and did some editing to the pg db. I'm super confused as to why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue previously. It worked for me, when I tried after sometime.