# Heroku CLI hangs on Windows 10

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I use Heroku CLI on Windows 10. The first day after installing it works just fine, but on the next day (or so) it just hangs after launch:

```
C:\Users\{User}>heroku
```

and that's all. No output to console, no logs (no error.log). It lasts forever (not 120 sec like here: [Heroku CLI Unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356149/heroku-cli-unresponsive))

I reinstalled CLI on 10.10.2017. Today is 14.10, my folder contains the following files:
[folder view before cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9OsA.png)
The autoupdate.log contains:

```
[2017-10-10T13:36:14+03:00] starting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin\\heroku.cmd update --autoupdate` from
heroku-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.14.34-1fcf80e
heroku-cli: Updating plugins... done
[2017-10-11T22:36:40+03:00] starting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin\\heroku.cmd update --autoupdate` from logs
heroku-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.14.34-1fcf80e
heroku-cli: Updating plugins... Waiting for all commands to finish
heroku-cli: Updating plugins... done
[2017-10-14T01:13:34+03:00] starting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin\\heroku.cmd update --autoupdate` from logs
heroku-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.14.34-1fcf80e
heroku-cli: Updating plugins... Waiting for all commands to finish
```

What have I tried:

- uninstall and install again - this one works, but I don`t want to do
  this every day
- running as administrator
- waiting all night long
- using different commands (heroku --version, heroku update etc)
- delete folder ..\AppData\Local\heroku

After deleting the folder and running command 'heroku update' the following files & folders were created, but console still hangs:
[folder view after cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS6Hj.png)

The autoupdate.log consists now of 1 line:

```
[2017-10-14T19:39:02+03:00] starting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin\\heroku.cmd update --autoupdate` from update
```

I waited for an hour since and now writing this question here. Has anyone faced such an issue? What can be done?

**Update**
Finally I made it work after a few days by reinstalling CLI several times and deleting the autoupdate files, but cannot say precisely which of my actions had true effect. If you face the same issue you can start with the Malik`s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and i followed these steps to fix it.

1. Go to heroku AppData directory. (windows run `%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku`)
2. You should see 2 files named as autoupdate and a directory named as update.lock.
3. Delete these 2 files and the directory.
4. Open a new cmd window.
5. Try running the `heroku` cmd again. Now it should work for you.

I use following version

- heroku-cli/6.14.36  , (windows-x64) , node-v8.9.0.

[Relevant github issue thread](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/623)

Comment: Hi Malik, thanks for response! I got it finally working a few days after my question: reinstalled several times, deleted autoupdate file and other folders in various combinations and thanks god it works fine for now. I guess your solution is right and it has to do with the autoupdate file.

Comment: Glad it worked for you . If you think my Answer is correct , Please mark it as the accepted Answer so that it will help somebody else with the same problem :)

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same problem when I run *`$ heroku login`* on **`GitBash`** for Windows.

I tried the accepted answer above but to no avail. What solved it was just to use ***`Windows Command Prompt`*** instead of **`GitBash`** and all problems were solved.

I'm just adding this answer here in case someone has done the same thing like I did.

Comment: This is the right answer to the problem... Just Windows command prompt or your engine's traditional command prompt. Gitbash doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Using `GitCMD` instead of `GitBash` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Using Windows Prompt instead of Gitbash also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same symptom because I was behind a proxy but did not [set the proxy env vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy).

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
heroku login
```

Answer (score 0):

Usin CMD git for heroku login. I had to do the other steps using the bash and all was perfect.